# Why is this text not being colored by ncurses?

Tags: c++, colors, ncurses

I wanted to create a window in ncurses, surround it with a box, and write some colored text in it.

When I try to make simple colored text in the standard window it works perfectly, but when I try to put it in a new window the text appears white on black (i.e. the default)

Here's the code I've tried. Why doens't it work?

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    initscreen();
    WINDOW * win = newwin(8,15,1,1);
    box(win,0,0);
    start_color();
    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_RED);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    mvwprintw(win,1,1,"colored text");
    wrefresh(win);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you normally want to also have `endwin()` at the end of your code.

Comment: agreeing with the need for `endwin`, you could eliminate the `wrefresh` if you used `wgetch(win)`

Answer (score 22):

I soloved the problem by using

```
wattron(win, COLOR_PAIR(1));
```

instead of

```
attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
```

`wattron` affects the given window, while `attron` assumes you mean `stdscr`, rather than the current window.

Comment: Hey, I've added a line of explanation to your answer about why this change fixes the problem. Feel free to remove it if you don't want it there.

Comment: The next question is, how to access the current WINDOW* if you haven't run newwin() ever?In my case a only use the window that the app starts from.